# How can I remove duplicate records in Access only if all fields match?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that unfortunately has many duplicates.  Here is a small example:

> Name  |  Location
>   Mike  |  New Jersey
>   Mike | Ohio
>   Brian | Ohio
>   Mike | New Jersey

How can I only remove dups on the Mike | New Jersey lines?  I'm having trouble making sure all fields match and not just Name.  So my end result would be:

> Name | Location
>   Mike | New Jersey
>   Mike | Ohio
>   Brian | Ohio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier to do that in two steps:

1. Create a table without duplicates
2. Truncate original table and load data from table you just created

To create a Query that will remove duplicates, use Group By. E.g.

```
SELECT Name,Location
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Name,Location
```

Comment: Thank you both.  I guess I was looking at this in a much more complicated manner.  Oops.